# I'm trying to move a <span> for an animated menu inside of a <div> down, but it stays put, overlaying content in another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, menu

Thats not all... when I inspect through chrome for iPhone X it appears correctly and so for desktop as well. I'm using dreamweaver and when I choose to view directly from my device is where I see the problem. Image is directly from mobile device. Also wanting to move it a little out the corner, but nothing. Please help!  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzbyL.jpg

```css
.sidenav {
  height:50%;
  width: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 50px 8px 8px 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}


#button .span{
    margin:auto;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 5em;
    left:0;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="button">
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">menu</span>
</div>   

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Book</a>
  <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify what it is you want to do.

Comment: I want the menu to be in the bottom left corner when on a mobile device.